# How to make WebBrowser to save its content as an MHT file?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, com, browser, extensibility

Internet Explorer can save its content as an MHTML file using the "Save As..." menu command. Is this feature exposed by its COM interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It is.

Try something like:

```
WebBrowser.ExecWB OLECMDID_SAVEAS, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER
```

BTW to do MHT conversion manually, check out the [code by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx?fid=104741&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2381970).